# Create event -stimulate a surname

Tags: javascript

I have find on w3school a stimulate '*' with createevent and now I am trying to create a surname "Markous Max". Markous is my name and the Max my surname.Is this possible can be done in same line?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
div {
  padding:50px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
</style>
<script>
function myFunction(event) {
var x = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
x.initMouseEvent("mouseover", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);

document.getElementById("myDiv").dispatchEvent(x);
}
</script>



<div onmouseover="this.innerHTML += 'M';" id="myDiv"></div>
<div onmouseover="this.innerHTML += 'a';" id="myDiv"></div>
<div onmouseover="this.innerHTML += 'r';" id="myDiv"></div>
<div onmouseover="this.innerHTML += 'k';" id="myDiv"></div>
<div onmouseover="this.innerHTML += 'o';" id="myDiv"></div>
<div onmouseover="this.innerHTML += 'u';" id="myDiv"></div>
<div onmouseover="this.innerHTML += 's';" id="myDiv"></div>
<div onmouseover="this.innerHTML += '';" id="myDiv"></div>
```

Simulate Mouse Over

Comment: Check my edited answer. Does it solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same id `myDiv` for multiple divs. An id can be used only with one element. So, replace the `id` with `class` for each of your div.

In the JS, get the elements by `className`, loop through each of the element, and dispatch the event.

See the below snippet for more details -

```js
function myFunction(event) {
  var x = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
  x.initMouseEvent("mouseover", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);

  //Get elements by className - 
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("myDiv");
  
  //loop through each of the element
  for(let i = 0; i<elements.length; i++){
    //dispatch the event for each of the elements
    elements[i].dispatchEvent(x);
  }
}

//Firing the function here. This will call the function only one time. You can create a button and call this function onclick.
myFunction(event);
```

```css
body{
  display: flex;
}

div {
  padding:50px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!--Replace id with class-->

<div onmouseover="this.innerHTML += 'M';" class="myDiv"></div>
<div onmouseover="this.innerHTML += 'a';" class="myDiv"></div>
<div onmouseover="this.innerHTML += 'r';" class="myDiv"></div>
<div onmouseover="this.innerHTML += 'k';" class="myDiv"></div>
<div onmouseover="this.innerHTML += 'o';" class="myDiv"></div>
<div onmouseover="this.innerHTML += 'u';" class="myDiv"></div>
<div onmouseover="this.innerHTML += 's';" class="myDiv"></div>
<div onmouseover="this.innerHTML += '';" class="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: You can use `display: flex` in css to deal with that. Check my edited answer (snippet)